# Llamar a función PHP desde tpl usando AJAX Prestashop

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, prestashop

He creado una pagina en prestashop usando PHP y su correspondiente archivo .tpl. El objetivo es introducir el alto y el ancho de un pdf y que el archivo PHP con la librería FPDF me genere un pdf con ese tamaño. El archivo .php tiene el siguiente código:

```
<?php
class NadieControllerCore extends FrontController
{

public $php_self = 'nadie';

public function initContent()
{
parent::initContent();
if(isset($_GET['action']) && !empty($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = $_GET['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'getPDF' : getPDF();break;
        // ...etc...
    }
}

$this->setTemplate('nadie');

}


public static function getPDF(){
ob_start();
require('vendor/fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm',array(20,10));
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Output();
}


}
```

El fichero tlp el siguiente:

```
{extends file='page.tpl'}
{block name='page_title'}
<span class="sitemap-title">{l s='Plantilla descargable' d='Shop.Theme'}</span>
{/block}
{block name='page_content_container'}
<section>
<p><label>Introduce ancho:</label> <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="8" size="10" /></p>
<p><label>Introduce alto:</label> <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="8" size="10" /></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
    $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'GET',
                data: {action:'getPDF'},
                url: 'NadieController',

                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            }
    );
}
</script>
</section>
{/block}
```

Al ejecutar la pagina me muestra el siguiente error:
[image: Error Ajax]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debe a que el sistema de templates smarty trata de interpretar las llaves del código javascript como si fueran directivas de template. Para que esto no ocurra debes usar una etiqueta [`{literal}`](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/es/language.function.literal.tpl):

> Las etiquetas literal permiten que un block de datos sea tomado literalmente, no siendo interpretado por el smarty. Esto es generalmente utilizado alrededor de bloques javascript o stylesheet, en donde pueden haber sintaxis delimitadoras que puedan interferir con el template. Cualquer cosa dentro de las etiquetas {literal}{/literal} no es interpretado, si no desplegado tal como esta.

El código quedaría entonces:

```
{literal}
<script>
function myFunction() {
   ...
}
</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: Efectivamente se ha solucionado el error, ahora el problema está en la URL de la consulta AJAX que no me funciona. ¿Alguna solución?